# Testing simple (conditional) effects in orthogonal contrasts for three levels

Tags: interaction, contrasts

I would like to test the `y ~ x` relation across 3 groups by the means of a set of two orthogonal contrasts codes.

When dealing with two groups, I examine the simple effect in each group by codding the group of interest as `0`. However, I am not sure how to generalize this approach when dealing with two orthogonal contrasts.

Example:

```r
# Generate data ------------------------------------------
set.seed(1234)
Ngroups <- 3
NperGroup <- 1000
N <- Ngroups * NperGroup
groups <- factor(rep(1:Ngroups, each = NperGroup))
g <- rep(c(1, 4, 5), each = NperGroup) # simple effects
x <- rnorm(N)
e <- rnorm(N, sd = .1)
y <- x*g + e

# Orthogonal contrasts -----------------------------------
# Opposes G1 to G2&G3
C1 <- dplyr::case_when(groups == 1 ~ -1/2,
                       groups == 2 ~ +1/4,
                       groups == 3 ~ +1/4)

# Opposes G2 to G3
C2 <- dplyr::case_when(groups == 1 ~ 0,
                       groups == 2 ~ -1/2,
                       groups == 3 ~ +1/2)

print(C1 %*% C2 == 0) # test orthogonality

# Fit model ----------------------------------------------
print(summary(lm(y ~ x*(C1 + C2)))$coefficients)
```

`C1` is significant. How can I test the simple `y ~ x` relation within each level of `C1`; that is, for group 1 and for group 2&3.

To examine the `y ~ x` relation for group 1, I can set group 1 to `0` in both `C1` and `C2` without breaking the orthogonality:

```r
C1.g1 <- C1 + 1/2
print(C1.g1 %*% C2 == 0) # still orthogonal
print(summary(lm(y ~ x*(C1.g1 + C2)))$coefficients)

#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)   -0.001      0.003  -0.312    0.755
# x              1.000      0.003 321.661    0.000  <- simple effect of group 1
# C1.g1          0.002      0.005   0.332    0.740
# C2             0.008      0.004   1.935    0.053
# x:C1.g1        4.670      0.005 919.769    0.000
# x:C2           0.997      0.004 226.728    0.000
```

1. How can we properly test the `y ~ x` relation for group 2&3 (simultaneously).
2. How would we proceed to examine the simple effects for each level of `C2`?

Comment: 1. test that relation for which hypothesis? 2. to evaluate simple effects just use model `lm(y ~ x:groups + groups-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the simple effect of `y ~ x` for both group 1&2 (simultaneously), we can use the following set of contrast codes:

```r
C1.23 <- dplyr::case_when(groups == 1 ~ 1,
                          groups == 2 ~ 0,
                          groups == 3 ~ 0)

> print(summary(lm(y ~ x*(C1.23 + C2)))$coefficients)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.00029     0.0022    0.13    0.895
# x            4.50194     0.0022 2046.56    0.000 <- simple effect of both group 2&3
# C1.23       -0.00126     0.0038   -0.33    0.740
# C2           0.00848     0.0044    1.93    0.053
# x:C1.23     -3.50221     0.0038 -919.77    0.000
# x:C2         0.99750     0.0044  226.73    0.000
```